# Need info on SAML 2.0

Tags: java, saml

For web based Single Sign On (SSO) We need to implement as per SAML2.0 Standard specification. Would appreciate if any one provides some info on how to use OpenSAML2.0 using JDK 1.4.

Answer (score 4):

OpenSAML is a low-level lib, providing building blocks.  Consider something higher level, such as OpenSSO or Shibboleth-IdP, which could meet your needs.

Also review https://stackoverflow.com/users/33905/metadaddy answers.

Answer (score 0):

From the OpenSAML 2.2.3 readme file:

- OpenSAML, to date, has only been tested on JDK 1.5 but support for 1.4 is planned for the final 1.0 release.

I don't know what this means when the release version is well past 1.0.